# Splitting text and background as preprocess of OCR (Tesseract)

Tags: c++, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am applying OCR against text in TV footage. (I am using `Tesseact 3.x` w/ `C++`)
I am trying to split text and background part as a preprocessing of OCR.

With usual footage, text and background is highly contrasted (such as white against black) so that modifying gamma would do the job.
However, this attached image (yellow text with background of orange/red sky) is giving me hard time to do preprocessing.

[image: Yellow-text over orange sky]

What would be a good way to split this yellow text from background?

Comment: Have you tried to use `opencv` to threshold the image to extract the yelllow text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple solution by using `Python 2.7`, `OpenCV 3.2.0` and `Tesseract 4.0.0a`. Convert `Python` to `C++` for `OpenCV` should be not difficult, then call `tesseract API` to perform OCR.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

def show(title, img, color=True):
    if color:
        plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1]), plt.title(title), plt.show()
    else:
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray'), plt.title(title), plt.show()

def ocr(img):
    # I used a version of OpenCV with Tesseract binding. Modes set to:
    #   Page Segmentation mode (PSmode) = 11 (defualt = 3)
    #   OCR Enginer Mode (OEM) = 3 (defualt = 3)
    tesser = cv2.text.OCRTesseract_create('C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tessdata/','eng', \
                                          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',3,3)
    retval = tesser.run(img, 0) # return text string type
    print 'OCR Output: ' + retval

img = cv2.imread('./imagesStackoverflow/yellow_text.png')
show('original', img)

# apply GaussianBlur to smooth image, then threshholds yellow to white (255,255, 255)
# and sets the rest to black(0,0,0)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5), 1) # smooth image
mask = cv2.inRange(img,(40,180,200),(70,220,240)) # filter out yellow color range, low and high range
show('mask', mask, False)

# invert the image to have text black-in-white
res = 255 - mask
show('result', res, False)

# pass to tesseract to perform OCR
ocr(res)
```

**Processed Images and OCR Output (see last line in image):**

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: @Aki24x any comment to the above answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  The result looks good!  Just a once follow up question, you chose "(40,180,200),(70,220,240)" as a range to filter out.  How did you decide the range?  I also tried to filter out with color range programatically before, but it failed.  Probably that is because my color range was too wide.

Comment: @Aki24x Glad to have your positive feedback. I picked the color range manually by a [color picker](http://colorcop.net/). Just did few attempts then got the result correctly.

Comment: sorry for taking time to reply to you - you might have worried about it.  So  it was manual picking, then I want to try next would be how to make it automated since different footage require different color range to properly filter out.  Do you happen to have any idea??

Comment: @Aki24x It's ok. Just in my mind. (1) segment the footage text from background, (2) take an average of the color of the text then add upper and lower limit, say +/- 15, to the average as the color range and (3) perform pre-processing to extract the text before passing to tesseract. It would need more efforts to get a good result. You may open another question with sample video clip, typical footage information if any and sample code if you attempted to solve the question to get more feedback from SO community.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise.  Once we got more sample footage, I will create an another item with sample code if possible.  My goal is automating text detection, so auto-detection for filtering color/range would be my next target.  Thank you very much!