# reading watermeter digits with pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to read my watermeter digits with tesseract but It returns only empty strings.

the water meter image looks like this: [image]

I read the image with opencv

and then I try to run this:

```
image = "./asset/test5.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(image)
ret,img = cv2.threshold(np.array(img), 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
return text
```

but an empty string is returned ... Any hints for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the output of the `cv2.threshold` line. Most probably there are no numbers there.

Comment: See this [splitting-text-and-background-as-preprocess-of-ocr-tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621225/splitting-text-and-background-as-preprocess-of-ocr-tesseract/43642548#43642548) if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tesseract` is used mostly for documentation kind reading. I can suggest you to use `EasyOcr` which is a good option for these kind of scenarios. I have downloaded your sample image and here is the output of code given below.

> 0167 m

Here is the code sample:

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_sim','en'])
result = reader.readtext('/ur/path/image/img.jpg')
print(result)
```

**Note:** If your image quality becomes higher, I believe you can read the numbers properly.

[Here](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) is the link for EasyOCR.

Comment: That looks really good. Thanks I gonna try this later this evening.

Comment: Hi @Yunus I tried it. Same Image and your code example. But I Never got a nearly close result. Every Time different numbers....

Comment: Ah sorry I got it. didn't saw the correct output. Its there.

Comment: Happy to hear its working