# Poor Result in Detecting Meter Reading Using Pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract, meter

I am trying to develop a meter reading detection system. This is the picture
[image]

I need to get the meter reading 27599 as the output.
I used this code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('read2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(H, W) = gray.shape

rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20, 7))

gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 3), 0)
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, rectKernel)

res = cv2.threshold(blackhat, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV  + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config='--psm 12 --oem 3 digits')
```

I get this output:

```
'.\n\n-\n\n3\n\n7\n\n7\n\n3\n\n-2105 566.261586\n\n161200\n\n310010\n\n--\n\n.-\n\n.\n\n5\n\x0c'
```

This is my first OCR project. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the input image. It would be interesting to see the `res` image presented to Tesseract. Clearly it managed to read _some_ of the digits. I suspect the LCD figures are too big. Try cropping out the smaller digits, _and_ try shrinking the overall image size so those LCD digits are about as many pixels high as the correctly recognized digits. Update your question with any + / - progress reports. I am willing to believe that --psm 12 is useful; it's not the only setting to try. Do we really need --oem 3 ?

Comment: There's a lot of noise in your image. Try cropping a Region Of Interest (ROI) containing only the numbers before passing it to tesserract.

Comment: Resizing the image actually helped. I am getting 27559. It's not totally correct yet. I needed 27599. Thanks a lot for that tip. --oem 3 is actually not necessary @J_H.

Comment: you may use easyOCR, because tesseract isdesgned mostly for the documentation kind of cases. EasyOCR is more better than tesseract in real world examples. you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011514/11048887)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of texts there that can be removed before we start reading the actual meter number. On the other hand, we can limit our OCR to just numbers in order to prevent false positives (As a few 7-segment numbers are like alphabetical letters).

Since tesseract is not working well enough on 7-segment numbers. I will use EasyOCR.

So the procedure would be like this:

1. There are large spaces around the actual counter which can be cropped.
2. we blur the image and run a Hough transform to get the circular meter.
3. We for sure know that the number is in the upper half of that circle so we again crop based on the center and radius of the detected circle.
4. the cropped image then can be fed to EasyOCR and as i said previously only limited to the English language and numbers.

---

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import easyocr

cropped = orig_image[300:850,:][:,200:680]
cropped_height, cropped_width, _ = cropped.shape

gray = cv.cvtColor(cropped, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (17,17),0)
```

[image]

```
minDist = 100
param1 = 30 
param2 = 50
minRadius = 100
maxRadius = 300

circle_img = cropped.copy()
circles = cv.HoughCircles(blurred, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
print(f"{len(circles)} circles detected", circles[0,:][0])
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv.circle(circle_img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

circle = circles[0,:][0]
circle_center = (circle[0], circle[1]) # x, y
circle_radius = circle[2]

color_cropped = cropped[circle_center[1] - circle_radius : circle_center[1],:]
```

[image]

```
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext(color_cropped, allowlist ='0123456789')
if result:
    print("detected number: ", result[0][1])
```

detected number: 27599